# Updating arrayAdapter of a view from outside of the Fragment class

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-studio

I'm following Udacity's Developing Android Apps course, which is quite good till now.

Just for trying new things out, I decided to make a few changes in the code to tidy it up.

Original code basically contains a class extends Android's Fragment class, which also includes another class to get weather data from openweathermap.org API, in a seperate thread.

I decided to move communication, presentation and API conversion features on seperate classes, because it was way too cluttered initially (again, this is just for self-education purposes. Original code works just fine).

Now I have a ForecastFragment class:

```
public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment {

    ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        //This is just a placeholder until we fetch the real data from web
        String[] data = {"Fetching data from server"};

        List<String> forecast = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(data));

        mForecastAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(
                getActivity(),
                R.layout.list_item_forecast,
                R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,
                data);

        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listViewForecast);
        listView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

I have another two other classes:

One that gets the pure JSON from the server

```
public class Comm extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        //Network operations 
        return responseFromServer;
    }

   protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        //Here should come the code which should update the view
    }
}
```

And another one which converts JSON to a String[] (`ApiConverter` class). I'm skipping the details of this one, because it works just fine. It basically takes the raw JSON string and returns a string array.

Now, the problem is, since Comm class does its main work on another thread, I have to update the view in Comm.onPostExecute(). Otherwise main thread is executing all code before Comm class do its thing and I get an empty string.

I thinked about copying the ForecastFragment's onCreateView code to Comm class, but it felt like I'm violating the DRY principle. besides, ForecastFragment class is already instantiating a copy of the Array Adapter, instantiating another with a copied code is a waste of resources.

I have clumsly tried to write a code to get the current instance of ForecastFragment, but hardly failed.

I also tried to change the ForecastFragment to a singleton, following the instructions [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_singleton.htm). It seems parent Fragment class prevents me from doing it (and I am not certain even if I could do it, I could accomplished what I want).

I can write Comm class as a sub-class of ForecastFragment and reach the class variable from there, but I'd like to know if there is a better way while keeping the classes seperate.

So, what would be a reasonable way to accomplish this while keeping the communication and presentation classes seperate?

Comment: what about creating an `interface` inside the `comm class`, implement that in `fragment` class and in `onPostExecute()` method call the required method, this way you can keep the classes seperate

Comment: Say I did that, how can I use it in the `Comm` class?  I tried several ways but it won't compile.

Comment: I will post some code for you, meanwhile can you add what you did or what is not compiling ?

Comment: Here is what I've tried: 

`public class Logger {

    public interface loggerInterface{

        public void log();

    }

    public void useExternalLog() {
        //Here I have tried: 
        //Extender.log()
        //log()
        //but both gives error. 
    }

}`

`public class Extender implements Logger.loggerInterface{

    public void log() {
        Log.v("Interface Test", "testing interfaces");
    }

}`

I can use it within the Extender class, but not within the Logger class.

Comment: you can place the AsyncTask class in your fragment class (inner class) and move initializing  `mForecastAdapter` to `onPostExecute()`

Comment: Yes, actually that is what the original code does, and that is the easy way. But since this is not a real problem, I'm just looking for the other possible solutions which does not require nested classes. Because I want to keep the codes strictly seperate (if possible, of course).

Comment: then make an Interface , say `TaskCompleteListener` which have a method `onTaskCompleted(String param);` `ForecastFragment` should implement it i can post a sample if you want

Comment: Ok I will post some code as soon as get back on my system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can make interface, which have the method you want to call when task complete

the Fragment should implement this interface

the AsyncTask should take an instance of class the implements this interface, in our case the calss will be ForecastFragment.

in the task, `onPostExecute()` call that method `onTaskComplete()`

**The interface:**

```
public interface TaskCompleteListener {
    public void onTaskComplete(String dataArray);
}
```

**ForecastFragment:**

```
public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment implements TaskCompleteListener {

    ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        //This is just a placeholder until we fetch the real data from web
        //String[] data = {"Fetching data from server"};

        new Comm(this).execute("params...");

        return rootView;
    }

    @override
    public void onTaskComplete(String dataArray){
        data = parseJson(dataArray);
        List<String> forecast = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(data));
        mForecastAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(
                getActivity(),
                R.layout.list_item_forecast,
                R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,
                data);

        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listViewForecast);
        listView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);
    }
}
```

**the task Comm:**

```
public class Comm extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private TaskCompleteListener taskCompleteListener = null;

    public Comm(TaskCompleteListener taskCompleteListener){
        this.taskCompleteListener = taskCompleteListener;
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        //Network operations 
        return responseFromServer;
    }

   protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        //Here should come the code which should update the view
        taskCompleteListener.onTaskComplete(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Eyvallah :) I'll try it when I am back at home. Just one question: Is it possible to implement this so that it takes the particular instance of `ForecastFragment` that has been already instantiated by the system?

Comment: Aaaand it worked. It felt like woodoo when implementing the solution, but then I realized how neat it is :) Thanks a lot. And by the way, when passing the ForecastFragment instance to the `Comm` class, I realized it IS the actual class that has been instantiated already. So all is good now.

Comment: @SercioSoydanov exactly it's the same one, as you are passing `this` and not a `new Forecast...` happy for you :)